# coffee script - use parameter vairable in json data

Tags: json, coffeescript

I have a coffee script function

```
postData: (pattern) ->
  myData =
    a: "a string"
    pattern: 0
    f: false
```

It is evaluated as

```
{
  "a": "a string",
  "pattern": 0,
  "f": false
}
```

It is not what I want. I would like `pattern` to be a string I passed in

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
postData: (pattern) ->
  myData =
    a: "a string"
    f: false
  myData[pattern] = 0
  return myData
```

See it working [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:postData%20%3D%20(pattern)%20-%3E%0A%20%20myData%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%22a%20string%22%0A%20%20%20%20f%3A%20false%0A%20%20myData%5Bpattern%5D%20%3D%200%0A%20%20return%20myData%0A%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(postData('junk')%2C%20null%2C%202))).